# Firefox 18 - unexpected transitionend event behavior / strange event bubbling

Tags: events, firefox, css-transitions

In Firefox 18.0.1 I am experiencing some unexpected behavior from the transitionend event. I am unable to find any detailed description of this particular event on either MDN or in the W3C documentation - does anyone have an opinion on whether this is a bug or not?

In this particular case the transition is related to the change of height of a DIV containing a number of other DIVs in turn containing a number of CANVASes. The transition and the event is attached to the outer DIV.

- While the event prior to FF 18 was fired only once at the end of the transition, it now fires a great number of times.
- The events are always bubbling up from the contained CANVAS objects.
- Seven transitionend events will fire for each CANVAS, the only difference in the event data being the propertyName. It will "iterate" through seven different color-related css properties (color, border-color, --moz-xxx proterties etc) for each CANVAS.

At a loss here. Working around this will require a significant rewrite. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Transitionend events do bubble per spec, and fire for each property being transitioned.  I don't believe this would have changed with Firefox 18, offhand.  Hard to say more without seeing your testcase.

If you're looking for a somewhat detailed description of these events, see http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/#transition-events

Comment: Thank you - this was useful. Seems the behavior of a multiple events (one per attribute) is correct, but in this particular case it also seems both the list of affected attributes as well as the firing of the event in the first place is wrong.

Comment: OK.  I'd still love to see a testcase; it's hard to say what you're seeing without that....